# Can't import Python module located on root directory from a different path

Tags: python, flask

```
Directory Structure:

    - / 
     - root
     - var
       - www
     - ...
```

In */var/www*, when  I try to import a python module, let's say *Library*, located in */root/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages*, it gives me an Internal Server Error.

But, it works well when I run the same script in the *root* directory.

How can I make it work in */var/www*? Any suggestions?

**Edit:**

```
import Library
...
```

Comment: _root/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages_ is not an absolute path.  _/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages_ is.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I meant that.

Comment: did you activate virtual environment? if you are using one

Comment: Yes. I have virtual environment active.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the path to your 'Library' to your Pathon search path. You can do this from within you Python script.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages')

import Library
```

Also you can add the path to your [PYTHONPATH environment variable](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path).